# Why is a controller in an api able to be accessed from an Identity Server base url?

Tags: identityserver4

I have an Identity Server 4 app and an ASP.NET Core API.  The IDServ app is on localhost:5000 and the API on localhost:31000 - however, I can access a get request on a ValuesController that lives in the API project using localhost:5000/values and get the response I am looking for....as if the api controller lives in the IDServ app, when it doesn't - you'd think I would have gotten a 404.  I can't find any documentation on this/why it can work that way - they're two separate applications.

So is this supposed to work this way, or could something be configured incorrectly?  If this is the intent, why/how?

Answer (score 1):

That makes no sense. Make sure your assumptions are true:

1. Are your services really running in those ports and not the other way around?
2. If so, are you sure you don't have a controller in your IDServ that serves /values?

> you'd think I would have gotten a 404

Yes, if 1 and 2 are true.

Comment: I agree it makes no sense.  No the controller does not exist in the IDServ project/app, it only lives in the API project/app - two different websites, but I can access that controller via the IDServ port (this works when deployed as well, it's not just local).  Interestingly enough, the dependencies for this controller do have to be registered in the IDServ startup as well as the API or it doesn't work (again, even though the controller lives in the API project).